# D3 and Leaflet - svg circles not showing

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to draw SVG circles on a map background, but while they are showing up in the elements (using Chrome Dev tools) they are not shown on the page. What am I missing here, why are they hidden?

I have tried to change the fill, opacity of the map and of the circle but I can't figure out why it isn't rendering?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Leaflet and D3 map</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../leaflet.css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../leaflet.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.js"></script>
                <style type="text/css">

                    #map{
                        width: 700px;
                        height: 600px;
                    }

                </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="map"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

                        //
                        // LOAD THE MAP FROM MAPBOX & LEAFLET
                        //
                        var map = L.map("map").setView([50.0755,14.4378], 12);

                        mapLink = '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>';
                        L.tileLayer (
                            "link to mapbox",{
                                attribution:"&copy; " + mapLink + " Contributors",
                                maxZoom:20,
                        }).addTo(map);

                        //
                        // Create the SVG layer on top of the map
                        //
                        L.svg().addTo(map);

                        // Create the standard variables selecting the SVG in the map element
                        var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg");
                        var g = svg.append("g");

            //Load the coordinate for the circle
            var objects = [ {"circle":{"coordinates":[50.0755,14.4378]}}];

            //Loop through to create a LatLng element that can be projected onto Leaflet map
            for(var i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
              objects[i].LatLng = new L.LatLng(objects[i].circle.coordinates[0], objects[i].circle.coordinates[1])
            };

            //Create the circle object and store it in features
            var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(objects)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .style("fill", "red")
            .attr("r", 20);


            //Make the circle dynamic, by calling the update function whenever view is view is reset
            map.on("viewreset", update)

            //Call the update also on first load of the web page
            update();

            //Updates the position of the circle every time the map is updated
            function update(){
              feature.attr("transform",
              function(d){
                return "translate("+
                    map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x+","+
                    map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y+")";
              })

            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, your circle is appended:

[image]

But, it is invisible not because of opacity or color, but because you don't set the dimensions of the svg. With default dimensions of the svg, your circle is beyond its border and consequently hidden (it resides in the middle of the map, at [350,300], while the default size of an svg is 300x150 *likely browser dependent*). Try:

```
 var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",700) 
    .attr("height",600)
```

As your map is 700 pixels across and 600 pixels high.